# Сделать перемещение элемента плавным

Tags: c#, winforms, .net

Что есть:
 Форма с двумя pictureBox'ами.

Чего требуется достичь:

Плавного перемещения pictureBox'ов

Мой код завязан на ловле трех событий от формы, mouseDown, mouseMove, mouseUp. Т.е. когда нажимается кгнопка мыши, флаг переключается в другое состояние, в MouseMove, если флаг истинный, выполняется изменение свойства Location picturebox'а. По mouseUp флаг переводится в неактивное состояние.
Все бы ничего, да толкьо вотд вижется оно как-то не очень красиво:
[image]

Господа, кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным? Почему так происходит и как можно сей эффект исправить?
Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Код:

```
  private void ClickOnMainForm(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
  {
            float percent = 0.75F;
            float part = (1F - percent) / 2;
            Rectangle imageRect;

            unchecked
            {
                int diagonal_width = (int)(part * Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((int)pictureBox1.Width, 2.0) + Math.Pow((int)pictureBox1.Height, 2.0)));


                int x_offset = (int)(Math.Sin(Math.PI / 4) * diagonal_width);
                int y_offset = (int)(Math.Sin(Math.PI / 4) * diagonal_width);
                imageRect = new Rectangle(x_offset, y_offset, (int)System.Math.Ceiling(pictureBox2.Width * percent),
                    (int)System.Math.Ceiling(pictureBox2.Height * percent));

            }
            //Определить попадание мыши в эти координаты
            if (e.Location.X <= imageRect.Width && e.Location.X >= imageRect.X &&
                e.Location.Y <= imageRect.Height && e.Location.Y >= imageRect.Y)
            {
                this.isMoveOn = true;
                oldMouseCoords.X = e.Location.X;
                oldMouseCoords.Y = e.Location.Y;
            }

            if (e.Location.X <= imageRect.Width && e.Location.X >= imageRect.X &&
                e.Location.Y <= imageRect.Height && e.Location.Y >= imageRect.Y)
            {
                this.isMoveOn = true;
                oldMouseCoords.X = e.Location.X;
                oldMouseCoords.Y = e.Location.Y;
            }
}

private void FormOnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
if (this.isMoveOn)
        {
            Point moveVector = new Point();
            //pictureBox1.Visible = false;
            moveVector.X  = oldMouseCoords.X - e.Location.X;
            moveVector.Y  = oldMouseCoords.Y - e.Location.Y;
            if ((sender as Control).Name == "pictureBox1")
            {
                pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X -  moveVector.X, pictureBox1.Location.Y -  moveVector.Y);
                this.pictureBox1.Invalidate(true);
                this.Invalidate();

            }
            if ((sender as Control).Name == "pictureBox2")
            {
                pictureBox2.Location = new Point(pictureBox2.Location.X - moveVector.X, pictureBox2.Location.Y - moveVector.Y);
                this.pictureBox2.Invalidate(true);
                this.Invalidate();
            }
            oldMouseCoords.X = e.Location.X;
            oldMouseCoords.Y = e.Location.Y;
            //pictureBox1.Visible = true;
        }
private void DoMouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        dragModeOn = false;
        isMoveOn = false;
    }
```

Comment: Окей, срочно добавляю код

Comment: Просто ради интереса, сам ниразу не пробовал. Вы как то перенаправляете события от контролов на форму или есть спец флаг, что бы PictureBox'ы не ловили события?

Comment: Есть спец флаг

Comment: Советую перейти на WPF

Comment: @MilkyCoder, уже. Но там все ужасно сложно и запутано. Читал сегодня книгу и ничего не понял вообще.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/164705/) человек развивал "экстремальные" скорости отрисовки WinForms, но лучше почитать [продолжение](http://habrahabr.ru/post/164885/) статьи. Со [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690426/why-do-my-winforms-controls-flicker-and-resize-slowly).

От себя посоветую использовать дельту больше единицы для движения мыши.

Answer (score 1):

У меня все рисуется нормально.

```
public partial class MainDialog : Form
{
    private bool capture;
    private Point prevLocation;

    public MainDialog()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private Point TranslatePoint(Control control, Point point)
    {
        var pt = control.Location;
        pt.Offset(point);
        return pt;
    }

    private void pnlBlock_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (capture)
        {
            return;
        }
        capture = true;
        prevLocation = TranslatePoint(pnlBlock, e.Location);
    }

    private void pnlBlock_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!capture)
        {
            return;
        }

        var newLocation = TranslatePoint(pnlBlock, e.Location);
        {
            var dx = newLocation.X - prevLocation.X;
            var dy = newLocation.Y - prevLocation.Y;

            if (dx == 0 && dy == 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            pnlBlock.Location = TranslatePoint(pnlBlock, new Point(dx, dy));
        }
        prevLocation = newLocation;
    }

    private void pnlBlock_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        capture = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Включите в настройках формы параметр DoubleBuffered и будет вам немного счастья.

Comment: то же самое