# Помогите с динамическим созданием picturebox

Tags: c#, picturebox

Есть код в котором я загружаю картинку, могу двигать её где угодно в пределах panel1 и после я могу нажать button2 и у меня сохраниться скриншот panel1. Загвоздка в том что я никак не могу реализовать это для нескольких картинок. Допишите код, если не трудно, буду благодарен.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace kyrsova
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //pictureBox2.BackColor = Color.Transparent;

        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Image img = Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);


                pictureBox1.Image = img;
            }
        }

        private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (coun == 1)
            {
                pictureBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(e.X - 50, e.Y - 50);
            }
        }
        int coun = 0;
        private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (coun == 0)
                coun++;
            else coun = 0;

        }



        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(panel1.Width, panel1.Height);
            pictureBox1.Size = bmp.Size;
            panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, panel1.Width, panel1.Height));
            pictureBox2.Image = bmp;

            SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
            sfd.DefaultExt = "bmp";
            sfd.Filter = "Image files (*.bmp)|*.bmp|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)

                bmp.Save(sfd.FileName, ImageFormat.Bmp);


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А что конкретно у вас не получается? Из вопроса не ясно

Comment: @eastwing загрузить много изображений

Comment: Может, создать несколько пикчурбоксов? Или вы хотите сделать множественный выбор в диалоге открытия картинки?

Comment: @eastwing Все равно, главное чтобы я мог перемещать изображения. Попробуйте потестировать код. Там можно выбрать 1 изображение и его перемещать. А я хочу чтобы я мог выбрать несколько и мог их перемещать по отдельности

Comment: Дополните вопрос в том смысле, что нужно создать на панели сколько угодно пикчурбоксов, каждый из которых можно таскать мышью. Я постараюсь ответить через несколько часов, если никто не ответит раньше

Comment: Не очень ясно, зачем скрин-шот панели вы пытаетесь запихнуть в PictureBox2?

Comment: @BlackWitcher я хочу на panel поместить картинки и после сделать скриншот панели . Не хотел  скриншотить всю форму

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понял вопрос, то нужно иметь возможность загружать разные картинки в разные PictureBox'ы, а потом иметь возможность перемещать любой из них по панели, и проблема именно в том, что не получается создать несколько PictureBox-ов.

В этом случае измененный код из вопроса будет таким:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    List<PictureBox> pb; //Это будет контейнер для PictureBox'ов
    PictureBox activePB; //Активный PictureBox, который перемещаем
    int coun = 0; //Эта переменная уже была, просто перенес её объявление сюда

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pb = new List<PictureBox>(); //Создадим списочек при инициализации формы
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //Если была выбрана и загружена картинка, то...
            Image img = Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            //...создадим новый PictureBox, загрузим в него картинку и укажем
            //дополнительные параметры для него.
            var picbox = new PictureBox();
            picbox.Parent = panel1;
            picbox.Image = img;
            picbox.Left = 10;
            picbox.Top = 10;
            picbox.Width = picbox.Image.Width;
            picbox.Height = picbox.Image.Height;
            //Назначим обработчик события MouseDown
            picbox.MouseDown += pictureBox1_MouseDown; 
            //Добавим созданный PictureBox в списочек
            pb.Add(picbox);
            //И сделаем его активным
            activePB = picbox;
        }
    }

    private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (coun == 1 && activePB != null) 
        {
            //Двигаем активный PictureBox, но я бы не стал делать координаты так
            //X-50, Y-50.  
            activePB.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(e.X - 50, e.Y - 50);
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (coun == 0)
        {
            coun++;
            //Назначаем активным PictureBox на котором кликнули.
            activePB = sender as PictureBox;
        }
        else
        {
            coun = 0;
            //Отпускаем PictureBox, хотя это получится, если размер PictureBox больше, чем 50 х 50.
            activePB = null;
        }

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(panel1.Width, panel1.Height);
        //Не ясно, зачем было это:
        //pictureBox1.Size = bmp.Size;
        panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, panel1.Width, panel1.Height));
        //И это не понял зачем: 
        //pictureBox2.Image = bmp;

        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sfd.DefaultExt = "bmp";
        sfd.Filter = "Image files (*.bmp)|*.bmp|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)

            bmp.Save(sfd.FileName, ImageFormat.Bmp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Просто красавчик)

Comment: Вопросик еще, как сделать чтобы можно было передвигать плавно изображения ?

Comment: Нужно подумать, так сразу и не скажу, но дергания тоже заметил... Надо поэкспериментировать, что тут можно сделать.

Comment: посмотри пожалуйста, если смогешь - напиши

Comment: Сегодня, наверное, уже вряд ли получится чисто по времени. Так что 100% обещать не могу. Если получится - дополню свой ответ и отпишусь тут.

Comment: Ок, очень жду))

Comment: С плавностью совсем [не так уж всё просто (англ. SO)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4691978/6935496). Вот, кстати, аналогичный [вопрос на русском](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/205169/222168). Если коротко, то так: сделать можно, но нужно много усилий.
А пока у формы можно поставить свойство **DoubleBuffered** в **true**, правда, это не сильно поможет.

И еще - чем больше картинка в пайнт-боксе, и чем больше пайнт-боксов, тем тормознее будет.